# how to link on mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo

I have been using mapinfo for some time now but I have not been able to complete the following task and I would very much welcome some help if anyone can offer it to me:

I have data which I need to link or join to railway lines or sections of adjacent railway lines. From this I would like to complete hot- spot lines of routes similar to thematic mapping to show troublesome routes.

I can do this using drivetime when there is a start X and Y and end X and Y point for the train data but the data I am working on does not have these. Instead I only have one geocoded data point which does fall on the railway line but I can not join it to the railway line. I would then need to thematically map these sections to show different widths for larger numbers.

I hope this makes sense to at least one of you.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to what you're trying to do. Are  you trying to spatially join the data to the railway lines based on nearest location?

Comment: Yes exactly that is it. And from that I would like to create hot spot lines of routes by thematically mapping them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Distance Calculator tool (under Tool Manager). You can use it to identify the nearest rail line to each geocoded data point you've got and output a unique ID from each table. You might get something like this:

```
+---------+--------+----------+
| PointID | RailID | Distance |
+---------+--------+----------+
| 1       | 2      | 1.8      |
+---------+--------+----------+
| 2       | 3      | 0.2      |
+---------+--------+----------+
| 3       | 7      | 0.9      |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

Once you've got that, you should be able to do an update or join on your existing data to match up the points to their nearest rail line object.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I will attempt and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hey. I tried this today and I successfully calculated distances to the railway lines. I updated a column on the table it produced too. . I'm now stuck with how to do a thematic map on this output as it was not possible to update the railway line table.

Comment: Why can't you update the railway line table?